# Как запустить музыкальный файл отдельно от программы

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь сделать шуточный скрипт который при открытии будет открывать сайты букмекерских контор под музыку, но когда я запускаю файл с музыкой то сайты не открываются, я пытался делать через subbpoces, через импортирование другого пайтон скрипта, но все тщетно

```
import webbrowser
import time
from playsound import playsound
import Uploader
import subprocess
subprocess.call("Uploader.py", shell=True)

while True:      
    webbrowser.open("https://leon.ru/")
    time.sleep(5)
    webbrowser.open("https://winline.ru/?a_id=30&data1=w36ejpjrado977imij9pd78g")
    time.sleep(5)
    webbrowser.open("https://www.olimp.bet/?modal=sign-up&utm_source=bookmaker-ratings.ru&utm_medium=refer&utm_campaign=refer_bookmaker-ratings.ru_rkolimp_button&utm_content=button&utm_term=all_land-promocode_fb30500-obzor&promocode=RB&click_id=wivovmiduqbs77im27na702u")
    time.sleep(5)
    webbrowser.open("https://www.ligastavok.ru/registration?utm_source=affiliates&ls=LigaPartners=lp-ugmrhz1_37284~UaG3rhFAdrH6SdoE&source=https://bookmaker-ratings.ru/&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fbookmaker-ratings.ru%2F")
    time.sleep(5)
    webbrowser.open("https://www.pari.ru/promo/rb25k/?affijet-click=158176440&partner_id=1318&utm_medium=Affiliate&sub_1=welfn3uhl1uhn7imierhc4bs")
    time.sleep(5)
    webbrowser.open("https://betboom.ru/welcome?utm_source=bookmaker-ratings&utm_medium=agregators&utm_campaign=january_&utm_term=main&utm_content=RBBB&click_id=wrh9cadnbjkmu7im2omkt112")
    time.sleep(5)
    webbrowser.open("https://www.fon.bet/promo/fb2000_welcome15/?affijet-click=158176471&partner_id=1536&utm_medium=affiliate&sub_1=&sub_2=&sub_3=&sub_4=wofb34tsecemr7imimh78g12&utm_referrer=https%3a%2f%2fbookmaker-ratings.ru%2f")
    time.sleep(5)
    webbrowser.open("https://1xstavka.ru/")
    time.sleep(5)
```

`
вот 2-ой

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound("audio_file.mp3")
```

мне хотелось бы что-бы работала и музыка и открывание сайтов, желательно все в одном файле
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я слышал что можно это как-то сделать при помощи pygame

Comment: Но я не знаю как это сделать)

Comment: Если что 2 файл где музыка воспроизводится называется Uploader

Answer (score 0):

Комментировать не могу, репутации нет, поэтому извините за неконкретный ответ.
Возможно поможет 2 параллельных процесса (музыка и открытие сайта). https://django.fun/ru/docs/python/3.10/library/multiprocessing/
может поможет литература

Comment: От себя добавлю, что на хабре есть хорошая статья на эту тему: https://habr.com/ru/post/149420/

Answer (score 0):

```
from playsound import playsound
import threading
threading.Thread(target=playsound,args=("audio_file.mp3",) ).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import playsound    
playsound.playsound(f'путь к файлу', block=None)
```

Проигрывание музыки в паралельном режиме.